# Fail to start TMG server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service, backupexec, microsoft-ftmg-2010

Is there any conflict between Backup EXEC 2010 Remote agent and TMG Server (on 2008 R2)?

Because when I install Backup EXEC 2010 Remote agent on TMG Server, server failed to start!!!

and after disable it's service in safe mode, solved...but Backup EXEC not working (because service not running)

Answer (score 1):

Backup Exec uses the Network Port 10000 TCP and this is already used by AD Web Services. Have a look in this Post:

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH60245

greetz

chris